# User specific details from log analytics workspace for ADLS

Tags: azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I am looking for user specific (eg: login details, who removed the file,load the file) details from log analytics workspace for ADLS gen2 account.

Kindly help.

Thanks,
Aswathi

I have tried storagebloblogs but which is giving only activity level details.